# Search for files in folders that have a dot in their name

Tags: windows-11, windows-search

1st, I want to cover what this question is **not** about.  There are 100's of articles that talk about how to search for **folders with dots within their names**.  This is not the question.  This is about searching for **files** within a folder that has dots in its name.

Say I have a folder

```
c:\public\dev\process.ui.help\
```

I have another folder

```
c:\public\processuihelp\
```

I have exact copies of the same files in each folder

```
help.csproj   
help.cs
```

help.cs has a line in it like

```
//find this - SearchForMe
```

if in explorer and I search "SearchForMe", then explorer only returns help.cs from the 2nd folder but not the first.  It may be treating the dotted folder names as extensions.

**Edit:** in the index options, any folders with extensions are automatically being de-selected.  If I reselect them and save, they are de-selected again.

Is there any work-around or alternative search?

Why? : In this large development project (10's of projects, 1000's of folders), I am using dotted folder names to organise namespaces without creating a deep hierarchy of folders.  Windows allows dotted folder names.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't searched with built-in windows searches for a long time.
I just replicated your situation and tried searching with "Search My Files" and with "Everything", two tools I use frequently and both found both files immediately. Maybe give either or both of them a try and see if they do what you are looking for.
Edit: Everything is by voidtools, search my files by nirsoft, both are freeware.

Comment: thank you for the referral and testing them out on my scenario.  Will give those a try as an alternative